# Changed SSH port but iptables refuse

Tags: ssh, iptables

I just changed my SSH port from the default 22. Now, I cannot access it anymore, my thought would be the firewall. I already added the new port to the iptables then do `sudo iptables-save`. However it is still not working. Here is my `iptables` rule:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 15 12:15:39 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:688]
:fail2ban-nginx-http-auth - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-nginx-http-auth
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 99999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 99999 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A fail2ban-nginx-http-auth -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 15 12:15:39 2014
```

*I changed my actual port with `99999` just for this public paste, but in my server that is not the port number I wish to replaced `22` with*.

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: @HBruijn See my edit buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters in iptables, rules are traversed sequentially.

```
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 99999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 99999 -j fail2ban-ssh
```

After dropping everything the subsequent rules will never be reached and have no effect. Your general DROP rule should be last.

Comment: I also sees that, however I just added `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 99999 -j ACCEPT` and that is where it is placed. How can I move it above `-A INPUT -j DROP`?

Comment: Use `iptables -L -n --line-numbers` and rather than using A (append at the end of the chain) use I (insert) followed by a position to place rules at the correct position when editing live firewall rules. Or edit the file you can create with `iptables-save > configfile` and reload (in a single transaction) after editing with `iptables-restore < configfile`

Comment: How can I insert `-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 99999 -j fail2ban-ssh` below `-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh`? I don't quite get using `-I INPUT`.

Comment: Don't worry about that. Simply save your current configuration to file `iptables-save > configfile`, use a text editor to move the `-j DROP` line to the bottom, and the run `iptables-restore < configfile`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you put the new `ACCEPT` rules after the `DROP` rule.

The rule `-A INPUT -j DROP` drops everything. No packet will reach the rule `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 99999 -j ACCEPT`.

Using `DROP` isn't the best idea either. If you want to ensure things work properly, you are better off using `REJECT` with appropriate responses. For example:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: Why `REJECT` over `DROP` then?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia some prefer to use REJECT over DROP as REJECT will inform the remote host that nothing is listening on that port, whereas DROP simply ignores the request.  In the case of an "honest mistake", REJECT is nicer as the remote host won't sit around waiting to hear back until it times out.

Comment: `1.` When debugging network problems use of `DROP` will cause the firewall to look like the culprit. If the real culprit is elsewhere, that will slow down debugging. `2.` Using `DROP` will be a help to anybody who tries to spoof your IP address. Proper error messages will make it obvious that spoofing is happening, and will in some cases reduce the impact of the attack. `3.` Some sites you connect to might try to connect back to you either to look for an ident daemon or possibly open proxy. Those will be slow for you, if you `DROP` their packets instead of sending an error back.

Answer (score 0):

When you change your SSH port, make sure that firstly, your sshd_config file is alright, if so, then run this command, where x is your destination port:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport x -j ACCEPT
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried that already. And I came up with my `iptables-save` above. Also seems that you are missing the option `-m`, why is that?

Comment: You are using different switch arguments. You are using -P and -m. Use -A and -p